# Renaming Attachments

Tags: python, arcmap, python-script-tool, attachments, photos

So I've been trying to download and re-name my attachments. I have been successful on ArcMap HOWEVER, the python tool I've been able to use only downloads one attachment per datapoint. I have multiple attachments per datapoint and would like to download them all.

The code that worked for me is https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/251829/165390
How can I edit this code to download multiple attachments? Is there a better Python tool out there?